# show that $g_n$ uniformly converges to $g$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

Let $U$ be a domain $\in \mathbb{R^d}$ (i.e. connected open subset). Suppose $f:[0,1]\times U\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $U$ such that $x_n$ converges to $x_0$. Show that $g_n(t):=f(t,x_n)$ uniformly converges to $g(t):=f(t,x_0)$ on $[0,1]$.

Could anyone check my attempt? Thanks!

Attempt: Let $A=\{x_0\}\cup (\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x_n\})$. Then $A$ is compact. So $[0,1]\times A$ is compact. So the restriction  $f|_{[0,1]\times A}$ is uniformly continuous. So $\exists \delta>0$ s.t. $(s,x_i), (t,x_j)\in [0,1]\times A$ and $\|(s,x_i)-(t,x_j)\|<\delta\implies  |f(s,x_i)-f(t,x_j)|<\epsilon$. On the other hand $$\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\,s.t.\, \forall n>N, \|x_n-x_0\|<\delta$$
So we have $|g_n(t)-g(t)|<\epsilon$ for all $t\in [0,1]$ since $\|(t,x_n)-(t,x_0)\|=\|x_n-x_0\|<\delta$

Comment: It's correct. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Looks good to me.